# How do I split one method into two smaller ones, one for input, and one for display?

Tags: c#

I am trying to split one method into two smaller methods - one that reads user input an array, and another to display this. It works if I have everything in one method but can't seem to make it work as per below. Thanks in advance.

```
{
        numbersArray();
        DisplayNumbers();

    }

    static void numbersArray()
    {
        //declare the array
        int[] numbers = new int[10];
        //get user input
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number: ");
            numbers[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }

    static void DisplayNumbers();
    {
    foreach(var n in numbers)
        {
            Console.Writeline(n);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should declare array of numbers outside of the functions since it is used by both:

```
    //declare the array
    private static int[] numbers = new int[10];

    static void numbersArray()
    {
        //get user input
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number: ");
            numbers[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }

    static void DisplayNumbers()
    {
        foreach (var n in numbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(n);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        numbersArray();
        DisplayNumbers();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried that. However, I am still getting an error with the DisplayNumbers method. I hope I didn't misunderstand you.

Comment: Nevermind. I tried it again (deleted and readded some lines), and it now works fine. Thanks. May I also ask if it's not too much bother... if I wanted to display the numbers in reverse,would I just add a Array.Reverse(numbersArray); in there somewhere? Thanks.

Comment: What's the purpose of using a static variable here instead of a local variable in `Main`? It's good to be in the habit of never using static variables outside of a couple of rare exceptions.

Comment: No particular reason @Tanner. I just followed other examples I saw elsewhere. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

```
static String[] numbersArray()
{
    private static String[] nums = new String[10];
    //get user input
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number: ");
        nums[i] = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    return nums;
}

static void DisplayNumbers(String[] nums)
{
    foreach (var n in nums)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(n);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{   
    DisplayNumbers(numbersArray());
}
```